# Chromium Browser (Linux Chrome) unable to display WebGL

Tags: google-chrome, webgl, linux-mint

I am running Chrome (chromium-browser on Linux Mint).

Version 22.0.1229.94 Built on Ubuntu 12.10, running on LinuxMint 14 (161065)

I can't seem to get webGL enabled on it, it has worked previously.

chrome://gpu shows "WebGL has been disabled, either via about:flags or command line."

So I have checked chrome://version/gpu

Which shows: Command Line    /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser --disable-new-tab-first-run --enable-user-scripts --flag-switches-begin --enable-accelerated-filters --disable-accelerated-2d-canvas --disable-gpu-vsync --disable-threaded-animation --disable-webgl --js-flags=--harmony --enable-nacl --enable-experimental-extension-apis --force-compositing-mode --ignore-gpu-blacklist --flag-switches-end

Which implies its getting disabled in the commandline. chrome://flags doesn't have webgl disabled.

/etc/chromium-browser/default only has CHROMIUM_FLAGS="--disable-new-tab-first-run --enable-user-scripts"

I have also tried running chrome direct via /usr/bin/chromium-browser

I can't see how this is getting disabled in the commandline. Is there something else I should change to enable it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only way I've managed to fix it, was to do a rm -Rf /home/(username)/.config/chromium. Removing the Default directory inside it wasn't enough. WebGL is now enabled as default, without any further changes.